# Fatal error: Call to undefined function get_header() in C:\xampp\htdocs\hypershot\index.php on line 13

Tags: wordpress, xampp

I have just purchased a WordPress template and I am trying to run this theme locally (XAMPP), and then when the site loads, it gives me the following error:

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function get_header() in C:\xampp\htdocs\hypershot\index.php on line 13

How can I proceed?

PS: I'm really sad about it now, as I thought it was going to be easy to deal with this template/theme! I just can't run the site (local).

Answer (score 4):

The error is:

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined function get_header() in C:\xampp\htdocs\hypershot\index.php
```

According to the WordPress folder structure, the `index.php` file in the root of your project should be something like this (`Version - 4.0`):

```
/**
 * Front to the WordPress application. This file doesn't do anything, but loads
 * wp-blog-header.php which does and tells WordPress to load the theme.
 *
 * @package WordPress
 */

/**
 * Tells WordPress to load the WordPress theme and output it.
 *
 * @var bool
 */
define('WP_USE_THEMES', true);

/** Loads the WordPress Environment and Template */
require( dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/wp-blog-header.php' );
```

But the error says that, you have an `index.php` file which has the `get_header()` function (WordPress function) inside it, so this `index.php` file belongs in the root of your `theme` folder, not inside the root of your project folder.

Since the `get_header()` is a WordPress function and WordPress is not loaded yet, PHP is throwing this error, because it doesn't recognize the `get_header()` function. So check the `index.php` file in your project's root and make sure that the right `index.php` file is there.

The best way to solve this problem is just reinstall a fresh copy of WordPress and then put the theme in your `C:\xampp\htdocs\hypershot\wp-content\themes` folder.